# regex to find multiple IP ranges in Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, ip

When using Python 3 with Regex I am getting unexpected results.  I want to do something like this

firstpass = re.findall('\s+((10|192|172).\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}/(\d+))', line)

Where it would look for spaces, then numbers starting with 10 or 192 or 172 and then any 3 octets after (IPv4 addresses).

I understand the grouping but I either get only one of the first three values.  Or if I change the grouping around I get get 3 returns (but still only 1 of the initial search values)  I've tried as many variations as I can read about.  the [10|192|172] just doesn't work.  inside () groupings of course.

I am looking for two return strings.  The IP and the mask.  It works fine until I try to enlarge my expression to have a more complex search.

the end goal is to look for ANY private IP space in one regex expression.

10.match.match.match
172.16-32.match.match
192.168.match.match

So the data may look like this and I want to pull 1 -3 but not the last line

```
B    10.50.13.0 /26 blah foo
O    192.169.5.0 /24 foo foo
B    172.18.0.0/16 etc etc
B    82.33.4.0/24 yak yak yak
```

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/d57ABN/1

Comment: OMG  the greatest site ever invented!  Thank you sir!  I need to get my head around word boundaries but it's what I needed for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape all dots (since you want to match them as literal chars), only use capturing groups around those patterns that you want `re.findall` to return and use non-capturing groups around the patterns you do not need it to yield, and use word boundaries.

```
re.findall(r'\b((?:10|192|172)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}\s*/(\d+))', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d57ABN/2).

See the [Python demo](http://rextester.com/IBZP47677):

```
import re
rx = r"\b((?:10|192|172)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}\s*/(\d+))"
ss = ["B    10.50.13.0 /26 blah foo", "O    192.169.5.0 /24 foo foo", "B    172.18.0.0/16 etc etc", "B    82.33.4.0/24 yak yak yak"]
for s in ss:
    print(s)
    m = re.findall(rx, s)
    if m:
        print(m)
    else:
        print("NO MATCH")
```

Output:

```
B    10.50.13.0 /26 blah foo
[('10.50.13.0 /26', '26')]
O    192.169.5.0 /24 foo foo
[('192.169.5.0 /24', '24')]
B    172.18.0.0/16 etc etc
[('172.18.0.0/16', '16')]
B    82.33.4.0/24 yak yak yak
NO MATCH
```

Comment: the ?: does't work unless I make it raw it seems.  Weird.  but yes this is what works.  The regex tester is perfect for where I am at with regex.  Thank you.  Word Boundaries.  My new topic of interest  :)

Comment: @Seth The word boundary should be defined as `r'\b'` or `'\\b'`. The `'\b'` is a backspace char. Non-capturing group syntax is not affected by the type of the string literal.